# Serialize input with html value using ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

I used jquery.ajax post to send the data to the server using c# but it handles an error
here's my code

```js
$(function(){
  $('#frmSubmit').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $(this);
    
    $.ajax({
      url: frm.attr('action'),
      type: frm.attr('method'),
      data: frm.serialize(),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(){
        alert('success');
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmSubmit" method="post" action="/announcement/create">
  Title:<br/>
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" /> <br/>
  Body:<br/>
  <textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea> <br/>
  
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
 </form>
```

My problem is when I input a html code on the textarea the result is error but when I input a normal text the result is okay, so my conclusion is that the serialized form won't accept any html code, I don't know why. please help me.

**New Update**
Actually... I'll use this method in order for me to store html content using trix-editor (WYSIWYG).. here's the [link](https://github.com/basecamp/trix)
but the problem is stated above... please help me to solve this guys...

Your response would be very much appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: why do you need ajax inside submit?

Comment: @user2181397, What is wrong in that ?

Comment: @user2181397 Just send the data from the from to the server side (c#)

Comment: @RayonDabre then what is purpose of form submit?

Comment: try getting the raw value of the textarea like this: $('div').html(decodeURI(that_string));

Comment: Each of these have their own benefits but you tell me what is wrong with the approach OP is attempting ?

Comment: One question `serialize` is spelled wrong in your question. `seriaize`? Is that accidental?

Comment: Please, post a sample content which cause issue. That might help.

Comment: form submit url/method  is same as ajax url/method , so shall i assume this form submit and ajax will serve different purpose?

Comment: @user2181397, Just assume that OP is missing `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @user2181397 not necessarily. May be they just don't want to refresh the page.

Comment: why do we need to introduce a submit button and to restrict its normal flow again introduce e.preventDefault()? Can it be done with button type button?

Comment: @OP, It is working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/cnxwnzpr/)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan then I guess button type = button will be better option

Comment: @user2181397, Why better ? Justify your statement.

Comment: @RayonDabre what you want me to justify ? It is awkward when some one with 6000 reputation ask such a question.button type submit and button type button , both has got a different purpose submit will refresh the page. I still dont understand why you want to use button type submit and then use e.preventDefault to restrict it's flow. Can you explain that

Comment: Could you use `on('submit'` handler with `type='button'` ? We could miss some accessibility benefits as well..You never know :)

Comment: @user2181397 What you need to remember is that a form gets submitted in different ways. You can click a Submit button, or a simple "Enter" key can trigger that. So if you just write something related to form submit action, it will be a stupid thing to handle using `click` event.

Comment: @user2181397 The best scenario where you want to submit a form using ajax and not refresh page, is to create a form `submit` handler, and use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the normal flow. Then do the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it!

Thanks to @Mitch for giving me an idea to use other attributes of the Ajax...

HTML:

```
<form id="frmSubmit" method="post" action="/announcement/create">
  Title:<br/>
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" /> <br/>
  Body:<br/>
  <textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea> <br/>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
 </form>
```

JS: But the only attribute I used is the contentType and I set it to `application/json` since I'm sending a data to the server through the use of `dataType:'JSON'`.

```
$(function(){
  $('#frmSubmit').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $(this);

    data = { 
      title: $("#title").val(),
      body: $("#body").val()
    } 

    $.ajax({
      url: frm.attr('action'),
      type: frm.attr('method'),
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(){
        alert('success');
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see. I replaced the serialized form with `JSON.stringify(data)` because I need to get all the data from the form and convert the value into JSON string since the `frm.serialize()` doesn't allow me to enter a value with HTML code.. It gives me an error which is the data is not sending to the server side during the debug session

Thanks to all those who tried to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your server side.
If you use ASP.NET, it has built-in request validation that automatically helps protect against XSS and HTML injection attacks. Your html content is treated as that.

There is several option to allow html content in post content:

1. Decorate the property on your model class that requires HTML with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

   ```
   public class DummyData 
   {
       public string Title { get; set; }        
       [AllowHtml]
       public string Body { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Add `[ValidateInput(false)]` on your method that receive post data. Bellow is sample with ASP MVC controller:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateInput(false)]   
   public ActionResult SaveYourData(DummyData model)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello @Dfirmansyah.. I get your point and I thought your answer would be my very solution but the problem is when i debug the server side by assigning a break point to the certain action of the controller... it doesn't really flowing on the break point during the debug session but the ajax telling that there must be a problem with the value I input on the textarea which is when i input some HTML code it gives an error even not flowing on the action but when I just input a normal text the debug session would flow on the break point... hope you get me...

Comment: It would not enter your action controller, because the validation is performed before your action method is executed.

Comment: about that If I enter a value with html code... but if I enter a normal text on the textarea it would enter to the action controller...

Comment: Yes, because normal text is valid data that's why it passed validation and enter your action method. But html text is treated as potentially dangerous data so it raise validation error and not continue to your action method. What I mean validation in this is HTTP request validation performed by ASP.NET not form input validation.

Comment: Ahh I see you're right i think thats the problem but... is there any other way to bypass the error validation with an html value to the textarea?

Comment: If it is from client side code(javascript), AFAIK there's none.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML Entities in your html text which you are pasting in your text area. Signs like 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

I have not used it myself. But after some googling I found that you need to Encode your html text into html entities before posting it. There are methods written by someone to encode and decode it (https://gist.github.com/CatTail/4174511).

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try example

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 



  </head>
  <body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/b.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="<html>" name="trxid" value="<?=$trx?>">
  <input type="" value="<td>" name="file">
  <input type="button" id="submit_custom" onclick="f(); return false;">
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function f(){   
      var frm = $('form');

      $.ajax({
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        data: frm.serialize(),

       /* need to be like this */
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       dataType: 'JSON',
       /**/

        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert('success');

  response = data;

  alert('response json value  '+response.a);
        },
        error: function(){
          alert('error');
        }
      });
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: Your code work, proble is with your server or your ASP code or what you use

Comment: This is the scenario... when I use the processData, contentType with JSON dataType the frm.serialize() accepts both normal text and with html code value but it's passing a null data to the server, and when I exclude the two attributes... frm.serialize() accept on the normal text and its passing a complete data to the server... but with html code... it still gives me an error without flowing on the server side...
I tried all of your code even you last post but it just give the same output... :(

Comment: try `var postData = new FormData(); postData.append('input_name', $('input').val(); postData.append('textarea_name', $('textarea').val();` // change to selectors for your input and textarea [data=data]. and replace serialize in post with `data: postData,`

Comment: also you can delete html tags in #c and after do rest of code. I `php` all work well

Comment: or repace html tag in js and after send tata with ajax post, but is not secure